# Windows 7: Intermittent Graphical Errors

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, gpu, graphics

Sorry if this is the wrong "Section" to put this question in, if so let me know and I will move it.

I seem to be having a intermittent graphical issue with my system which is normally seen as flickering coloured lines and graphical artefacts/boxes being rendered randomly on screen. I would normally put this down to a hardware issue on the GPU, however I have sent the card to ATI engineers who have verified that the card is functioning as expected.

Other posters seem to have had responses pointing towards issues with memory/RAM, I have used memtest86 to attempt to locate any memory errors, however so far all tests seem to have passed.

I have also installed the card + RAM in another machine which seemed to result in the same graphical issues (Only when both RAM + GPU were installed together).

Any ideas/advice you may have is appreciated, I will post the system specs below:

Thanks

### DxDiag:

### System Information

- Time of this report: 6/22/2014, 11:06:37
- Machine name: RON-PC
- Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144)
- Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
- System Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
- System Model: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
- B IOS: BIOS Date: 10/12/12 22:32:07 Ver: 04.06.05
- Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor            (8 CPUs), ~4.0GHz
- Memory: 8192MB RAM
- Available OS Memory: 8148MB RAM
- Page File: 4634MB used, 11660MB available
- Windows Dir: C:\Windows
- DirectX Version: DirectX 11
- DX Setup Parameters: Not found
- User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
- System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
- DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
- DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

---

### Display Devices

- Card name: AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
- Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
- Chip type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x6818)
- DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
- Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6818&SUBSYS_27401462&REV_00
- Display Memory: 4095 MB
- Dedicated Memory: 2030 MB
- Shared Memory: 2065 MB
- Current Mode: 2560 x 1440 (32 bit) (60Hz)
- Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
- Monitor Model: QHD270
- Monitor Id: ACH00FA
- Native Mode: 2560 x 1440(p) (59.951Hz)
- Output Type: DVI
- Driver Name: aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll
- Driver File Version: 8.17.0010.1280 (English)
- Driver Version: 14.100.0.0
- DDI Version: 11
- Driver Model: WDDM 1.1

Comment: Did the issue occur with the card you used when ATI engineers were testing the suspect card?

Comment: As far as I have seen the issues have only occurred with the "tested" card. I have another spare GFX card that I will try some additional tests with the suspect RAM.

Comment: What motherboard do you have? Have you updated BIOS on motherboard? Have you monitored your voltages and temperatures?  The newest video card drivers are 14.200.0.0.  (or 14.6 on amd website)